# Notepad++ does not show files mapped under "Z" drive

Tags: snap

Notepad++ installed from Ubuntu Software (snap package) maps the root FS to a "Z" drive.

But, when launched, File Open only shows the top level of directories under "/". For example, File Open will show /var but not /var/log - even though both of those directories are world-read.

Similarly, if NPP is launched against, for example, /var/log/syslog (when that file is made world-readable) - NPP shows the error "Can not open file 'Z:\var\log\syslog'".

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snaps are *designed to prevent access* to unusual places (like system directories), so this seems like expected behavior.

Snaps use multiple layers of permissions:

- Snapd Interfaces
- The snap's AppArmor profile
- The filesystem ownership and permissions.

Take a look at https://snapcraft.io/docs/snap-layouts for an example of how snaps are designed to keep guardrails up between nosy tourists and the spinning gears.

If you want full access to all files for yourself, a snap-based text-editor may not be the best way to go. Instead, you have other options:

- A deb-based or manually installed text editor
- On Snap-only Ubuntu Core, you can use the built-in `vim` editor
- You can copy the file to a readable location (like your /home)
- If you're being denied access to a commonly-used location, consider filing a bug report with the snap's author so they can explicitly add permission.

There's really no simple way to *override* a snap application's access permission. That would be a glaring security hole.

Comment: Thanks for this clear and complete explanation